# Batch icon message on task bar

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Is it possible to make a Batch, or .vbs if needed, is it possible to make batch have a little icon down there with the flag, battery and volume.

I want it to be a "Shutting down in xx minutes/hours", and mayyybbe clicking it cancels' it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: this info is contained in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify`  ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I know how to accomplish part of what you want -- making a systray balloon tip by borrowing from PowerShell.  But I don't know how to make it listen for dismissal of the balloon.  Maybe someone else can offer another answer building upon mine?

Anyway, I use this for a conversion script I made to convert flac to mp3 in batches.  Feel free to hack it for your own evil purposes.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

for %%I in (*.flac) do (

    rem // This initiates the systray balloon.
    call :systray converting from "%%~nxI" to "%%~nI.mp3"
)

goto :EOF

rem // Here's the :systray function
:systray <message>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "args=%*"
set "args=!args:'=''!"
set "code="[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms');^
$o=New-Object Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon;$o.Icon='%systemroot%\System32\PerfCenterCpl.ico';^
$o.BalloonTipIcon='Info';$o.BalloonTipText='!args!';$o.BalloonTipTitle='%~nx0';$o.Visible=1;^
$o.ShowBalloonTip(10000);Start-Sleep -M 12000;$o.Dispose();Exit""
start /b "" "powershell" %code%
endlocal & goto :EOF
```

The *n* values in `$o.ShowBalloonTip(`*n<sub>1</sub>*`)` and `Start-Sleep -M`*n<sub>2</sub>* are in milliseconds.  Salt to taste.

---

**Update:** I found a bit about registering an event for `$o.BalloonTipClicked` as well as a [lovely example in the wild](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/10/02/weekend-scripter-tea-time.aspx).  Basically, replace this:

```js
$o.ShowBalloonTip(10000);Start-Sleep -M 12000;$o.Dispose();Exit
```

... with this:

```js
$o.ShowBalloonTip(10000);register-objectevent $o BalloonTipClicked clicked;^
if (wait-event clicked -t 12) {$true} else {$false}; $o.Dispose(); Exit
```

You also need to execute `powershell` in a single threaded apartment for the event to work.

```js
start /b "" "powershell" -STA %code%
```

Now, you need to figure out how to make that relevant back in the context of your batch process.  For one thing, you'd probably no longer be able to use `start /b` to make the balloon tip non-blocking, and you'd probably use a `for /F` loop to capture the output of the `powershell` command.

Adding to your worries, I propose that "Shutting down in xx minutes" is not entirely user-friendly.  What if "Shutting down in 30 minutes" appeared 29 minutes ago, but the user just now saw it?  "Shutting down at 9:51 AM" might be better.

So with all this in mind, since what you want is event driven and since the batch language doesn't handle date-time math all that easily, I suggest doing the whole damn thing in PowerShell.  Save this with a `.ps1` extension.  Right-click and run with PowerShell.  Or if you want to execute it from a `cmd` console, do `powershell ".\scriptname.ps1"`.

```js
set-executionpolicy remotesigned

if ([threading.thread]::CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() -eq "MTA") {
    & powershell.exe -window minimized -sta $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
    exit
}

[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')

$minutes = 30
$launch_time = (Get-Date).AddMinutes($minutes).ToShortTimeString()

$o = New-Object Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$o.Icon = "$env:SystemRoot\System32\PerfCenterCpl.ico"
$o.BalloonTipIcon = "Info"
$o.BalloonTipText = "Shutting down at $launch_time"
$o.BalloonTipTitle = "Shutdown pending..."
$o.Visible = 1
function show-balloon { $o.ShowBalloonTip($minutes * 60 * 1000) }
show-balloon

$o_hover = [Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler]{ show-balloon }
$o.add_MouseMove($o_hover)

register-objectevent $o BalloonTipClicked clicked

if (wait-event clicked -t ($minutes * 60)) {
    remove-event clicked
    $o.BalloonTipText = "Have a nice day!"
    $o.BalloonTipTitle = "Shutdown aborted"
    $o.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
    if (wait-event clicked -t 10) { remove-event clicked }
} else {
    # Initiate shutdown sequence on my mark.  Authorization rojo alpha 3.  Mark.
    stop-computer
}

unregister-event clicked
$o.Dispose()
```

Bill_Stewart, if you're reading this, I know you're pleased.  As it happens, PowerShell is indeed the correct tool for the job this time.

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to make it work on my new code :3 But I havent forgotten you hehe