# Open a file through cmd and display the selected in specific editor

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

Open cmd in a specific location Example D:/text
And only show the files with the .txt extension 
Example

```
Dir..../D:/text
Text1.txt
Text2.txt
Text3.txt
```

And add the function to select the text1 or 2 or 3
Using a numbers or something like

> 1- Text1.txt
>
> 2- Text2.txt
>
> 3- Text3.txt

And after selecting 1 or any, open the file with a specific program without changing the default app opening in windows (notepad)
I wanna open the .txt file with sublime text editor (portable version)

And all this in a batch file.

Comment: And how do you prefer your coffe? I don't see any question but a request. Please, at least read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

You should at least show us what did you tried as code until now !
This a little starting to list text files with numbers and counting them :

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
SET "ROOT=%~dp0"
SET "EXT=*.txt"
ECHO -----------------------------------------------
ECHO Listing text files on this folder - "%ROOT%"
ECHO -----------------------------------------------

SET "Count=0"
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
REM Iterates throw the files on this current folder.
REM And Populate the array with existent files in folder
FOR %%f IN ("%ROOT%\%EXT%") DO (
    SET /a "Count+=1"
    set list[!Count!]=%%~nxf
)

set Files=%Count%
ECHO.
rem Display array elements
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Files%) do echo file number [%%i] : "!list[%%i]!"
SET /a "COUNT_TOT=%Count%"
ECHO.
ECHO Total of text files(s) : %Count% file(s)
EndLocal
PAUSE>nul
```

***EDIT : on 25/07/2016 @21:28***

I download and setup ***[Sublime Text 2](http://www.portalprogramas.com/en/sublime-text-portable/32bit/download#downloading)*** just for giving a try on my computer !

***Upadte Version with Sublime Text 2***

```
@ECHO OFF
Title Open the selected file with Sublime Text
:MenuLoop
Cls & Color 0A
SETLOCAL 
SET "ROOT=%~dp0"
SET "EXT=*.txt"
SET "Count=0"
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
REM Iterates throw the files on this current folder.
REM And Populate the array with existent files in folder
FOR %%f IN ("%ROOT%\%EXT%") DO (
    SET /a "Count+=1"
    set list[!Count!]=%%~nxf
)

echo wscript.echo Len("%ROOT%"^) + 15 >"%tmp%\length.vbs"
for /f %%a in ('Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\length.vbs"') do ( set "cols=%%a")

set Files=%Count%
set /a lines=%Count% + 10
Mode con cols=%cols% lines=%lines%
ECHO ********************************************************
ECHO   Folder : "%ROOT%"
ECHO ********************************************************
ECHO.
rem Display array elements
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Files%) do echo [%%i] : !list[%%i]!

SET /a "COUNT_TOT=%Count%"
ECHO.
ECHO Total of text files(s) : %Count% file(s)
echo(
echo Type the number of what file did you want to open ?"
set /p "Input="

For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) Do (
    If "%INPUT%" EQU "%%i" (
        Rem Testing if sublime_text.exe exist to open with it the text file
        If Exist "%programfiles%\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe" (
            Start "Sublime" "%programfiles%\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe" "!list[%%i]!"
            Rem Otherwise we open the text file with defalut application like notepad
            ) else (
            Start "" "!list[%%i]!"
        )   
    )
)   
EndLocal
Goto:MenuLoop
```

***Edit on 28/07/2016 @14:15***

***Upadte version with sublime text 3 and listing files in sub-directories***

```
@ECHO OFF
REM : To download Sublime Text 
REM https://www.sublimetext.com/3
Title Edit the selected file with Sublime Text 3
:MenuLoop
Cls & Color 0A
SETLOCAL 
SET "ROOT=%~dp0"
SET "EXT=*.bat"
SET "Count=0"
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
REM Iterates throw the files on this current folder.
REM And Populate the array with existent files in folder
FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b /s "%ROOT%\%EXT%"') DO (
    SET /a "Count+=1"
    set "list[!Count!]=%%~nxf"
    set "listpath[!Count!]=%%~dpFf"
)

echo wscript.echo Len("%ROOT%"^) + 18 >"%tmp%\length.vbs"
for /f %%a in ('Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\length.vbs"') do ( set "cols=%%a")
If %cols% LSS 30 set /a cols=%cols% + 10
set Files=%Count%
set /a lines=%Count% + 10
Mode con cols=%cols% lines=%lines%
ECHO  *******************************************************
ECHO   Folder : "%ROOT%"
ECHO  *******************************************************
rem Display array elements
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Files%) do echo [%%i] : !list[%%i]!

SET /a "COUNT_TOT=%Count%"
ECHO.
ECHO Total of [%EXT%] files(s) : %Count% file(s)
echo(
echo Type the number of what file did you want to edit ?
set /p "Input="
set "sublimeEXE=%programfiles%\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"
For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) Do (
    If "%INPUT%" EQU "%%i" (
        Rem Testing if sublime_text.exe exist to open with it the text file
        If Exist "%sublimeEXE%" (
            Start "Sublime" "%sublimeEXE%" "!listpath[%%i]!"
            Rem Otherwise we open the text file with defalut application like notepad
            ) else (
            Start "" Notepad.exe "!listpath[%%i]!"
        )   
    )
)   
EndLocal
Goto:MenuLoop
```

Comment: Definitely, got it running nice and smooth. Very good, it's clearly one more of your gems, a shiny piece of computational art. Congrats again man. You da guy. Tried out this version 3 and run as good as heaven.

Comment: @statosdotcom Did you tried [Multi-Ping Tester with colors ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636170/pinging-multiple-pcs-and-adding-text/38648766#38648766)