# How do I open a file with notepad in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

How do I open a file with a name like "translist-sales.txt.201607290045" in a batch file?  I have a folder where many of the file names that I have to open - in Notepad are named like above where only the end number changes by getting bigger.  How do I set up a batch file to open one of these files in notepad?

Comment: Here's a link on how to iterate over files in a folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180741/how-to-do-something-to-each-file-in-a-directory-with-a-batch-script

Comment: You can take a look at this code ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524510/open-a-file-through-cmd-and-display-the-selected-in-specific-editor/38525929#38525929

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this one:

```
start notepad C:\translist-sales.txt.201607290045
```

write this line to an empty txt file, then save it as run_me.bat with ".bat" extension. This must do it.

Answer (score 0):

You type notepad followed by it's name.

```
notepad "c:\somefolder\translist-sales.txt.201607290045"
```

Press *Winkey + R*, type `shell:sendto`, in the sendto folder right click and select *New - Shortcut*. Type `Notepad` in the wizard. Click to the end. Rename it something sensible. Now you can right click any file - *Send To - Notepad*.